# Accessing the "default show" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, overriding, typeclass

Say you have a data-structure (borrowed from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2529663/67579)):

```
data Greek = Alpha | Beta | Gamma | Delta | Eta | Number Int
```

Now one can make it an instance of `Show` by appending `deriving Show` on that instruction.

Say however we wish to show `Number Int` as:

```
instance Show Greek where
    show (Number x) = show x
    -- ...
```

The problem is that one must *specify* all other parts of the `Greek` data as well like:

```
    show Alpha = "Alpha"
    show Beta = "Beta"
```

For this small example that's of course doable. But if the number of options is long, it requires a large amount of work.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to access the "default show" implementation and call it with a wildcard. For instance:

```
instance Show Greek where
    show (Number x) = show x
    show x = defaultShow x
```

You thus "implement" the specific patterns that differ from the default approach and the remaining patterns are resolved by the "fallback mechanism".

Something a bit similar to method overriding with a reference to `super.method` in object oriented programming.

Comment: Sure, just use a newtype wrapper like in the almost-correct but deleted answer.

Comment: The correct way of  doing this is to have `.. deriving Show` and then have some pretty print class (or just a function) which displays the data however you like. Also, there is no such thing as method overriding in Haskell, or `super.method`, because there is no sub typing in Haskell.

Comment: The  `show` function is supposed to generate a string containing an Haskell expression that, once evaluated, gives the original value back. If you need something else, you should declare a different function (possibly in its own class).

Comment: @chi: then (a) why can it be overriden (one could make a function defined on the objects), and (b) why are infinite lists collapsed into an array literal?

Comment: (a) because sometimes the constructors are not exported so you have to override it (see e.g. Data.Set) (b) I don't completely understand your point, but you would be right to say that the contract is broken for infinite lists e.g. `read (show [[1..],[2]])` will not get the original list back. That being said, it's true that the contract is often broken in application code, so what you are trying to do is not uncommon. Sometimes it's quite convenient to just override `show` to be more readable and forget Haskell syntax.

Comment: But even when `show` doesn't produce valid Haskell syntax it's still generally regarded as programmer-oriented. It's "show me be a textual representation of the data so I can tell what it is", *not* "display this value as text for the end user". In python terms it's `repr`, not `str`. So showing some `Greek` values in a way that's indistinguishable from integers is a little bit of a code smell.

Comment: That's why you'll find so many questions on SO about how to make `show` render `String` values without the quotes, or lists without the brackets. Too many standard instances treat `show` as outputting code for it to really easy to use it for display purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sorta accomplish this using Data and Typeable. It is a hack of course, and this example only works for "enumerated" types as in your example.

I'm sure we could get more elaborate with how we do this, but to cover your given example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable

data Greek = Alpha | Beta | Gamma | Delta | Eta | Number Int 
             deriving (Data,Typeable)

instance Show Greek where
    show Number n = show n
    show x = show $ toConstr x
```

This approach as I've implemented it cannot handle nested data structures or anything else remotely fancy, but again, this is an ugly hack. If you really *must* use this approach you can dig around in the `Data.Data` package I'm sure you could piece something together...

Here is a blog post giving a quick introduction to the packages: http://chrisdone.com/posts/data-typeable

The proper way to go about this would be to use a `newtype` wrapper. I realize that this isn't the most convenient solution though, especially when using GHCi, but it incurs no additional overhead, and is less likely to break in unexpected ways as your program grows.

```
data Greek = Alpha | Beta | Gamma | Delta | Eta | Number Int 
         deriving (Show)

newtype SpecialPrint = SpecialPrint Greek

instance Show SpecialPrint where
    show (SpecialPrint (Number x)) = "Number: " ++ show x
    show (SpecialPrint x) = show x

main = do
    print (SpecialPrint Alpha)
    print (SpecialPrint $ Number 1)
```

Comment: I think you could achieve a similar thing to the first variant using [generic-deriving](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.7.0/docs/Generics-Deriving-Show.html), which would probably also handle nested things (as long as everything is `Generic`).

Answer (score 11):

As @phg pointed above in the comment this can be also done with the help of [generic-deriving](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module Main where

import           Generics.Deriving.Base (Generic)
import           Generics.Deriving.Show (GShow, gshow)

data Greek = Alpha | Beta | Gamma | Delta | Eta | Number Int
  deriving (Generic)

instance GShow Greek
instance Show Greek where
  show (Number n) = "n:" ++ show n
  show l = gshow l

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (Number 8)
  print Alpha
```

Answer (score 7):

No, that's not possible AFAIK.

Further, custom instances of `Show` deserve a second thought, because `Show` and `Read` instances should be mutually compatible.

For just converting to human (or whoever) readable strings, use your own function or own typeclass. This will also achieve what you want:

Assuming you have a `Presentable` typeclass with a method `present`, and also the default `Show` instance, you can write:

```
instance Presentable Greek where
    present (Number x) = show x
    present x = show x
```