# overriding default Eq definition for specific pattern

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have defined some data type that derives Eq but want to insert my own definition of (==) for some pattern. Is there any way to do this or do I have to define (==) for every pattern?

e.g.

```
data Asdf = One Char | Two Char Char --(deriving Eq)
instance Eq Asdf where
  (==) (One _) (One _) = True
  --otherwise use what the derived definition would have done
  --can I do this without defining these patterns myself?
```

Comment: Are you up for changing the definition of your datatype?  (e.g. can you change to `data Asdf = One (TrivialEq Char) | Two Char Char` where `TrivialEq a` is a newtype that always returns `True` for `(==)`?)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665917/accessing-the-default-show-in-haskell

Comment: Perhaps there's some Template Haskell library that can define the method of the default instance under a different binding. I'm not aware of it, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if writing an `Eq` instance that disagrees with "observational" equality is wrong per se but it doesn't exactly feel right.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, it's definitely not *inherently* wrong. For example, most interesting data structures admit multiple representations of most abstract values. There are also structures that cache redundant information that `Eq` needn't consider. It's a bit shadier, but still common, to define an `Eq` instance that ignores information that's *almost never* important. For example, a language implementation will often decree two expressions equal if they are alpha-equivalent, even if it would print them differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question discusses how to do something very similar for the `Show` instance, using the https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving package: [Accessing the "default show" in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665917/accessing-the-default-show-in-haskell)

See this answer in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385768/936310

I recently used it for the `Show` instance recently, and it worked wonderfully. You can similarly derive `Eq` as well for your type, assuming it's regular enough.

Answer (score 9):

To do what you're trying to do, you have to define it yourself, and that means you have to define it for every pattern.

Basically `data MyType x = A x | B x x deriving (Eq)` will add a default derivation equivalent to,

```hs
instance Eq x => Eq (MyType x) where
    A x1    == A x2     = x1 == x2
    B x1 x2 == B x3 x4  = x1 == x3 && x2 == x4
    _       == _        = False
```

Note that it figures out the necessary dependencies (the `Eq x =>` part above) as well as fills in the diagonal cases -- the special cases among the *n*<sup>2</sup> possible matches where the same constructor was used.

As far as I know, it does this definition all-at-once and there is no way to dig into an existing instance declaration to mess with it -- and there is a good reason for this; if they let you do this then that would mean that as codebases grow, you could not look at an instance derivation or a `deriving (Eq)` clause and be confident that you know exactly what it means, since some other part of the code might monkey-patch that `Eq` instance to do something nefarious.

So one way is to redefine the diagonal yourself. But *that's not the only way*. There is at least one alternative which may work if it's easier to modify several usage sites than to shove all *n* constructors into a single thing:

```hs
newtype EverythingIsEqual x = E x deriving (Show)
instance Eq (EverythingIsEqual x) where
    _ == _ = True

data MyType x = A (EverythingIsEqual x) | B x x deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

This `newtype` allows you to strategically modify certain terms to have a different `Eq` relation at no runtime cost -- in fact this is pretty much one of the two central arguments for newtypes; aside from the lesser one where "I want to have a type-level difference between these two Strings but they ARE just strings and I don't want to pay any performance penalty," there is the greater argument of "sometimes we want to tell Haskell to use a different `Ord` dictionary without messing with any of the values that this dictionary acts upon, we just want to swap out the functions."

Comment: It can also be enhanced with pattern synonyms to avoid having to match `A (E x)` everywhere.