# Haskell Cyclic Ord Relationship

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

I was trying to define a data type for rock paper scissors and came up with something like this:

```
data Hand = P | S | R deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord Hand where
  compare R P = LT
  compare P R = GT
  compare R S = GT
  compare S R = LT
  compare P S = LT
  compare S P = GT
  compare _ _ = EQ
```

While writing all that I was wondering if there's any way to define the data type to just have it derive Ord and then specify that
`compare R P = LT` and `compare P R = GT` instead of having to write all the comparisons by hand, for three elements it's okay but it would get tedious with each added element.

Comment: That's not an *order* relation.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28665917/67579

Comment: is this what you are looking for ?```data Hand = P | S | R deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)```

Comment: @tintin: probably not, since the rules of *rock-paper-scissors* are not an order relation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem gotcha, and rock paper scissors can not form a valid `Ord` relation ship.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you describe here is ***not* an order relation**. An order relation is:

1. *reflexive*, all values `x` are less than or equal tot itself;
2. antisymmetric: if `x` is less than or equal to `y` and `y` is less than or equal to `x`, then `x` is equal to `y`;
3. *transitive*: if `x` is less than or equal to `y`, and `y` is less than or equal to `z`, then `x` is less than or equal to `z`.

Your definition is *not* transitive. Indeed: `S` is less than `R`, `R` is less than `P`, but `S` is not less than `P`. I therefore would strongly advice you *not* to use `Ord`, since for instance sorting, etc. make use of these invariants.

What you can do is let it derive from `Ord` automatically:

```
data Hand = P | S | R deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

and then define a function `beats`:

```
beats :: Hand -> Hand -> Ordering
beats R P = LT
beats P R = GT
beats x y = compare x y
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this couldn't be an order relation. Adding the `beats` function achieves what I was looking for (not having to write all the compares).

Answer (score 3):

You can write generic variant of this function:

```
cyclicRelation :: (Bounded a, Ord a) => a -> a -> Ordering
cyclicRelation x y | x == minBound && y == maxBound = GT
                   | x == maxBound && y == minBound = LT
                   | otherwise                      = x `compare` y
```

Then just derive needed instances:

```
data Hand = P | S | R deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Bounded)
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked @freestyle's answer best and influencing by that just draw a Cirord type class which may be applicable to any such cyclic ordered data type like Pokemons etc :)

```
class (Bounded a, Ord a) => Cirord a where
  ccompare   :: a -> a -> Ordering
  cmax, cmin :: a -> a -> a

  ccompare x y = let mima = [minBound, maxBound]
                 in if x `elem` mima && y `elem` mima then compare y x
                                                      else compare x y

  cmax x y = if ccompare x y == LT then y else x
  cmin x y = if ccompare x y == LT then x else y

data Hand = P | S | R deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Bounded)
instance Cirord Hand

*Main> ccompare P R
GT
*Main> ccompare S R
LT
*Main> ccompare R S
GT
*Main> ccompare R P
LT
*Main> ccompare P S
LT
*Main> ccompare S P
GT
```