# Difference between deriving and instance in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a type which i have made an instance of `Show` class but i'm not getting the desired result. If i try to make it an instance of show class by using `deriving` word then it works but if try like:

```
instance Show (SomeValue v) where
  show (Null) = "You have no value"
  show (Justs v) = show (Justs v)

findKey key = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> if key == k then Justs v else acc ) Null
```

It goes in an un-ending loop(kind of). I think that default implementation works which i get by using `deriving` word what's wrong with the above code? it compiles but it does not print anything.

Is it possible that i print the value like this: (without "Justs")?

```
instance Show (SomeValue v) where
  show (Null) = "You have no value"
  show (Justs v) = show (v)
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665917/accessing-the-default-show-in-haskell

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's not same. For my data constructor i have only two values and for both of these values i have defined show but it does not print anything, i even tried to do with read by using type-annotations but it does not work :)

Comment: Of course it does not print anything, it is stuck an in infinite loop.

Comment: What will be the solution except using `deriving` word ? Excuses for so many questions :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
show (Justs v) = show (Justs v)
```

goes into an infinite loop for the same reason

```
f x = f x
```

does.

You can write it without the `Justs` as you asked, you only need a constraint on the instance

```
instance (Show v) => Show (SomeValue v) where
    show Null = "You have no value"
    show (Justs v) = show v
```

because if you are going to try to show a `v`, `v` should be showable, no?